# Eliminar movimientos en tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Buenas hize una aplicacion de tres en raya y a la hora de hacer los movimientos hay un movimiento que no se puede hacer y no se como implementarlo. Se supone que movimientos en diagonal salvo que estes en el centro o vayas hacia la casilla del centro no se pueden hacer y no sabría como ponerlo. Os dejo el código por si podeis decirmo como puedo ponerlo.
No se si crear otro metodo para implementarlo a la hora de los turnos de cada jugador pero las casillas son botones y no se si tendria que cambiarlo todo o hay alguna manera de decirle que no haga esos movimientos

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import PhotoImage
from tkinter import messagebox

class tres_en_raya():
  def __init__(self):
    self.jugador1="jugador1"
    self.jugador2="jugador2"
    self.ficha="ficha"
    self.jugador1=False
    self.jugador2=False
    self.X=0
    self.O=0
    self.colocacion=True
    self.combinacion=False

def colocar_fichas(self,x,y,b,c):
  if self.combinacion==False:
    if self.colocacion==True:#colocación de las trés fichas de cada jugador
      if self.O<3 or self.X<3:#condicion para completar las tres fichas de cada jugador
        if self.jugador1==True:#turno del primer jugador
          if  c.get()==" ":
            c.set("X")
            b=Button(self.raiz, textvariable=c,text=c,foreground = "red",bd=3,width=10,height=4,command=lambda:tres.colocar_fichas(x,y,b,c)).grid(padx=3,pady=3, row=x, column=y)
            self.jugador1=False# termina turno de jugador1
            self.jugador2=True #dá paso el turno del jugador2
            self.X=self.X+1
            tres.combinaciones_ganadoras("X")
          elif c.get()=="O":
            messagebox.showinfo(message='esa ficha no es tuya, prueba otro movimiento',title='Atencion!!')
          else:
            messagebox.showinfo(message='Aquí ya tienes una ficha tuya, coloca primero tus trés fichas',title='Atencion!!')            
        elif self.jugador2==True:
          if c.get()==" ":
            c.set("O")
            b=Button(self.raiz, textvariable=c,text=c,foreground = "blue", bd=3,width=10,height=4,command=lambda:tres.colocar_fichas(x,y,b,c)).grid(padx=3,pady=3, row=x, column=y)
            self.jugador2=False
            self.jugador1=True
            self.O=self.O+1
            print(self.O)
            tres.combinaciones_ganadoras("O")
          elif c.get()=="X":
            messagebox.showinfo(message='esa ficha no es tuya, prueba otro movimiento',title='Atencion!!')
          else:
            messagebox.showinfo(message='Aquí ya tienes una ficha tuya, coloca primero tus trés fichas',title='Atencion!!')
        else:
          messagebox.showinfo(message='pulsa start para comenzar',title='Atencion!!')
      else:
        self.colocacion=False
    
    elif self.colocacion==False:#aqui la condición cuandose ha terminado de colocar las fichas empezaria el juego
      if c.get()=="X" and  self.jugador1==True:
        c.set(" ")
        self.X=2
        print(self.X)
      elif  c.get()==" " and  self.jugador1==True and self.X==2:
        c.set("X")
        self.X=3
        b=Button(self.raiz, textvariable=c,text=c,foreground = "red",bd=3,width=10,height=4,command=lambda:tres.colocar_fichas(x,y,b,c)).grid(padx=3,pady=3, row=x, column=y)
        self.jugador1=False #termina turno de jugador1
        self.jugador2=True 
        tres.combinaciones_ganadoras("X")
      elif c.get()=="O" and self.jugador1==True:
        messagebox.showinfo(message='solo puedes mover tus fichas',title='Atencion!!')
      elif c.get()=="X" and self.jugador1==True:
        messagebox.showinfo(message='tienes que buscar una casilla vacia',title='Atencion!!')
      elif c.get()=="O" and self.jugador2==True:
        c.set(" ")
        self.O=2
      elif c.get()==" " and self.jugador2==True and self.O==2:
        c.set("O")
        self.O=3
        b=Button(self.raiz, textvariable=c,text=c,foreground = "blue", bd=3,width=10,height=4,command=lambda:tres.colocar_fichas(x,y,b,c)).grid(padx=3,pady=3, row=x, column=y)
        self.jugador2=False
        self.jugador1=True
        tres.combinaciones_ganadoras("O")
      elif c.get()=="X" and self.jugador2==True:
        messagebox.showinfo(message='solo puedes mover tus fichas',title='Atencion!!')
      elif c.get()=="O" and self.jugador2==True:
        messagebox.showinfo(message='tienes que buscar una casilla vacia',title='Atencion!!')
      elif c.get()==" " and self.X==3 and self.O==3:
        messagebox.showinfo(message='esta casilla aparece en blanco',title='Atencion!!')
      elif c.get()=="O" and self.jugador2==False:
        messagebox.showinfo(message='esta no es tu ficha, la tuya son las X',title='Atencion!!')
      elif c.get()=="X" and self.jugador1==False:
        messagebox.showinfo(message='esta no es tu ficha, la tuya son las O',title='Atencion!!')
      else:
        messagebox.showinfo(message='algo raro pasa',title='Atencion!!')
  else:
    messagebox.showinfo(message='se acabo',title='Atencion!!')
    Button(self.raiz,text="START",background = "green",foreground = "white",command=tres.start).grid(padx=10,row=5,column=2)


def start(self):
  self.colocacion=True
  self.combinacion=False
  self.jugador1=True
  Button(self.raiz,text="START",background = "gray",foreground = "red",command=tres.start,state=DISABLED).grid(padx=10,row=5,column=2)
  self.turno.set("Buena Suerte!!")
  self.texto1.set(" ")
  self.texto2.set(" ")
  self.texto3.set(" ")
  self.texto4.set(" ")
  self.texto5.set(" ")
  self.texto6.set(" ")
  self.texto7.set(" ")
  self.texto8.set(" ")
  self.texto9.set(" ")
  self.X=0
  self.O=0

def combinaciones_ganadoras(self,x):
  if self.texto1.get()==x and self.texto2.get()==x and self.texto3.get()==x:
    self.combinacion=True
    self.turno.set("Ganaste Jugador "+x)   
    Button(self.raiz,text="START",background = "green",foreground = "white",command=tres.start).grid(padx=10,row=5,column=2)
    
  elif self.texto4.get()==x and self.texto5.get()==x and self.texto6.get()==x:
    self.combinacion=True
    self.turno.set("Ganaste Jugador "+x)
    Button(self.raiz,text="START",background = "green",foreground = "white",command=tres.start).grid(padx=10,row=5,column=2)
  
  elif self.texto7.get()==x and self.texto8.get()==x and self.texto9.get()==x:
    self.combinacion=True
    self.turno.set("Ganaste Jugador "+x)
    Button(self.raiz,text="START",background = "green",foreground = "white",command=tres.start).grid(padx=10,row=5,column=2)
  
  elif self.texto1.get()==x and self.texto4.get()==x and self.texto7.get()==x:
    self.combinacion=True
    self.turno.set("Ganaste Jugador "+x)
    Button(self.raiz,text="START",background = "green",foreground = "white",command=tres.start).grid(padx=10,row=5,column=2)
  
  elif self.texto2.get()==x and self.texto5.get()==x and self.texto8.get()==x:
    self.combinacion=True
    self.turno.set("Ganaste Jugador "+x)
    Button(self.raiz,text="START",background = "green",foreground = "white",command=tres.start).grid(padx=10,row=5,column=2)
  
  elif self.texto3.get()==x and self.texto6.get()==x and self.texto9.get()==x:
    self.combinacion=True
    self.turno.set("Ganaste Jugador "+x)
    Button(self.raiz,text="START",background = "green",foreground = "white",command=tres.start).grid(padx=10,row=5,column=2)
  
  elif self.texto1.get()==x and self.texto5.get()==x and self.texto9.get()==x:
    self.combinacion=True
    self.turno.set("Ganaste Jugador "+x)
    Button(self.raiz,text="START",background = "green",foreground = "white",command=tres.start).grid(padx=10,row=5,column=2)
  
  elif self.texto3.get()==x and self.texto5.get()==x and self.texto7.get()==x:
    self.combinacion=True
    self.turno.set("Ganaste Jugador "+x)
    Button(self.raiz,text="START",background = "green",foreground = "white",command=tres.start).grid(padx=10,row=5,column=2)
  
  else:
    pass

def juego(self,x,y):
  self.turno.set("Esto funciona")

def interfaz(self):#pantalla interfaz principal
  self.raiz=Tk()
  self.nombre_usuario="Bienvenido!!!"
  self.raiz.geometry("345x360+0+0")
  self.turno=StringVar()
  self.texto1=StringVar()
  self.texto2=StringVar()
  self.texto3=StringVar()
  self.texto4=StringVar()
  self.texto5=StringVar()
  self.texto6=StringVar()
  self.texto7=StringVar()
  self.texto8=StringVar()
  self.texto9=StringVar()

  self.fondo=PhotoImage(file="pruebas python/tres en raya/v.gif",width=355,height=365)
  self.lblFondo=Label(self.raiz,image=self.fondo).place(x=0,y=0)
  
  self.turno.set("presione start")

  self.raiz.title(self.nombre_usuario)
  Label(self.raiz,text='3 en Raya',bg="black",fg="white",width=30,font="arcade").grid(padx=10, row=0, column=1,columnspan=4)
  Label(self.raiz,text=" ").grid(padx=10, row=1,column=0)
  self.b1=Button(self.raiz,textvariable=self.texto1, text=self.texto1,width=10,height=4,command=lambda:tres.colocar_fichas(2,1,self.b1,self.texto1)).grid(padx=3,pady=3, row=2, column=1)
  self.b2=Button(self.raiz,textvariable=self.texto2, text=self.texto2,width=10,height=4,command=lambda:tres.colocar_fichas(2,2,self.b2,self.texto2)).grid(padx=3,pady=3, row=2, column=2)
  self.b3=Button(self.raiz,textvariable=self.texto3, text=self.texto3,width=10,height=4,command=lambda:tres.colocar_fichas(2,3,self.b3,self.texto3)).grid(padx=3,pady=3, row=2, column=3)
  self.b4=Button(self.raiz,textvariable=self.texto4, text=self.texto4,width=10,height=4,command=lambda:tres.colocar_fichas(3,1,self.b4,self.texto4)).grid(padx=3,pady=3, row=3, column=1)
  self.b5=Button(self.raiz,textvariable=self.texto5, text=self.texto5,width=10,height=4,command=lambda:tres.colocar_fichas(3,2,self.b5,self.texto5)).grid(padx=3,pady=3, row=3, column=2)
  self.b6=Button(self.raiz,textvariable=self.texto6, text=self.texto6,width=10,height=4,command=lambda:tres.colocar_fichas(3,3,self.b6,self.texto6)).grid(padx=3,pady=3, row=3, column=3)
  self.b7=Button(self.raiz,textvariable=self.texto7, text=self.texto7,width=10,height=4,command=lambda:tres.colocar_fichas(4,1,self.b7,self.texto7)).grid(padx=3,pady=3, row=4, column=1)
  self.b8=Button(self.raiz,textvariable=self.texto8, text=self.texto8,width=10,height=4,command=lambda:tres.colocar_fichas(4,2,self.b8,self.texto8)).grid(padx=3,pady=3, row=4, column=2)
  self.b9=Button(self.raiz,textvariable=self.texto9, text=self.texto9,width=10,height=4,command=lambda:tres.colocar_fichas(4,3,self.b9,self.texto9)).grid(padx=3,pady=3, row=4, column=3)
  Label(self.raiz,text="").grid(padx=10)
  Button(self.raiz,text="START",background = "green",foreground = "white",command=tres.start).grid(padx=10,row=5,column=2)
  self.t=Label(self.raiz,textvariable=self.turno,text=self.turno,font="arcade").grid(row=6,column=2)
     
  self.raiz.mainloop()

tres=tres_en_raya()
tres.interfaz()
```

Comment: Un consejo, las preguntas que dependen de una librería o un tema en especifico debe estar etiquetadas con su respectivo nombre, por lo que veo esta es una pregunta de Tkinter más que todo y es recomendable etiquetarla bajo ese nombre para que otros usuarios puedan contestar esta pregunta y sea bien recibida o utilizada por otros usuarios con ese mismo problema.

Comment: Prueba a utilizar pygame necesitaras tiempo para aprenderlo, pero es mejor que tkinter para hacer juegos